# Google Analytics Event Tracking - compare multiple events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick, event-tracking

basically I have set up event tracking across my website.

I simply want to be able to compare two events, if this is possible? So I want to see who clicked on X and then what number of those then went to click Y on specific events.

If this isn't possible, could you please suggest alternative methods of how I could do with within the GA interface?

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, using Advanced Segmentation.

Basically, you'd set up an advanced segment for visits where users triggered Event X AND triggered Event Y. The resulting segment would show you visits where users who did *both* actions.

Note that this is limited to visit-level data; this won't show you users who triggered Event X in one visit, and then on a completely different visit, triggered Event Y. (This is a fundamental constraint of Google Analytics.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also now you can use events as goals: [See Google's blog post here.](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/04/new-google-analytics-events-goals.html) This seems still to be disabled for some localized languages (and some profiles).